# Sorting a struct with array pointer is not working

Tags: c, struct, quicksort, qsort

I'm creating two struct's: Deck and Card. I want sort the cards of the deck using qsort but this is not working. When I run an exception occurs: Segmentation fault. 
Follow my code:

```
typedef struct Card {
   int value;
}Card;

typedef struct Deck{
   Card *c[100];
   int top;
}Deck;

Card * newCard(int value) {
   Card * aux = (Card *)malloc(sizeof(Card));
   aux->value = value;

   return aux;
}

Deck * newDeck() {
   Deck * deck = (Deck *)malloc(sizeof(Deck));
   deck->top = 0;

   return deck;
}

void addCard(Deck *b, Card *c) {
   b->top++;
   b->c[b->top] = c;
}

int compare(const void *x, const void *y) {
   Card * xa = *(Card **) x;
   Card * ya = *(Card **) y;

   if(xa->value == ya->value)
      return 0;

   if(xa->value > ya->value)
      return 1;

   return -1;
}

void sort(Deck *b) {
   qsort(b->c, b->top, sizeof(struct Card*), compare);
}

int main() {
   Deck * b = newDeck();
   addCard(b,newCard(11));
   addCard(b,newCard(12));
   addCard(b,newCard(11));
   addCard(b,newCard(1));
   addCard(b,newCard(1));

   sort(b);

   return 0;
}
```

Someone can help me? I just want sort the cards of the deck but something is wrong with the logic. Probably something like pointer(malloc or calloc?).

Comment: Please provide a minimal compiled example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: your code is incomplete. please add full code. Off top of my head, you are accessing `Card` in `Deck` without allocating it....

Comment: `b->top++; b->c[b->top] = c;` Increase the variable _after_ adding, not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm....Your code seems like "fill in the blanks" since you have not posted your complete code and *the code that you have posted is correct*. So I completed your code in a way it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Your code
typedef struct Card {
   int value;
}Card;

typedef struct Deck{
   Card *c[100];
   int top;
}Deck;

int compare(const void *x, const void *y) {
   Card*  xa = *(Card **) x;
   Card*  ya = *(Card **) y;

   if(xa->value == ya->value)
      return 0;

   if(xa->value > ya->value)
      return 1;

   return -1;
}

void sort(Deck *b) {
   qsort(b->c, b->top, sizeof(struct Card*), compare);
}

// My main
int main() {
    Deck d;
    d.c[0] = calloc(1, sizeof(Card));
    d.c[0]->value = 5;
    d.c[1] = calloc(1, sizeof(Card));
    d.c[1]->value = 1;
    d.c[2] = calloc(1, sizeof(Card));
    d.c[2]->value = 3;
    d.top = 3;
    sort(&d);
    printf("%d %d %d", d.c[0]->value, d.c[1]->value, d.c[2]->value);
    return 0;
}
```

My guess in your segmentation fault is that you are accessing `Card` **without allocating it**.

**Update:**

your `addCard()` is incorrect. Here is correct one:

```
void addCard(Deck *b, Card *c) {
   b->c[b->top] = c;
   b->top++;
}
```

When you are adding cards, your `top` points place that you need to add card. So you need to increase it after adding. Just remember that you need to add checks for it too to prevent overflowing `Deck->c`.